# Open Source Reporting and Analytics for PHP (Logistics)

Tags: php, open-source, reporting, logistics

We're a small logistics company and want to be able to provide clients with a way to generate custom reports with their data in our shared database (limited by the relations built in the DB) as well a few standard reports that we will build for them.

We've looked into iDashboards and LogiAnalytics but the price tags are huge, and iDashboards have limitations on user sessions that directly obstruct how we deal with user logins (one company might have 10 people using the same User/Pass) so a "perpetual named session" is pretty unacceptable.

The ability to generate maps with the data (like a US map) and drill down to the city, county, or zip code level is also a must (though I would consider software that enables me to add this easily).

I've been searching, and searching, and have not found anything that looks useful thus far and am hoping someone out there has used something they liked and can make a recommendation.

If I can provide any more info about our requirements or needs, let me know and I'll gladly edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/), the license allow an unlimited number of report viewer users and also can do maps of pivot grids, besides it can connect to several databases and even plain text (CSV) files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [myDBR](http://mydbr.com). It will do everything you listed and much more.